# Try without Catch Error

Tags: java, compiler-errors, try-catch

I am writing a program to process serialized files. I am getting errors saying there is a try without catch in my openObjectInputStreamMethod. The thing is I have  both a try and catch in that method. Everything else seems to work fine. Any help will be great.

```
  public static ObjectInputStream openObjectInputStream( String fileName )
    throws IOException
  {
    /*
     *  This is a generic open method for an ObjectInputStream.
     *  Using the received String value (containing a file name), this method should
     *    create a new ObjectInputStream and return the reference to the newly  
     *    instantiated ObjectInputStream to the calling method.
     */
    try
    {
      inAccount = new ObjectInputStream(
                                         Files.newInputStream(
                                                               Paths.get("NewAccounts.ser" ) ) ) ;
      return new ObjectInputStream  // complete this statement.

    }  // end try block
    catch( IOException openError )
    {
      System.err.printf( "%nError opening %s", fileName ); // output an alert
      // rethrow/chain exception to be caught in main
      throw new IOException( String.format( "Error opening %s", fileName ), openError );
    }
  }  // end openObjectInputStream


  public static void closeObjectInputStream( ObjectInputStream ObjInStream )
  {
    /*
     *  This is a generic close method for an ObjectInputStream.
     *  Using the instantiated ObjectInputStream object, this method will close that object 
     */
    try
    {
      // The ObjectInputStream object will be null only if it was never successfully opened
      if ( ObjInStream != null )                     
        ObjInStream.close();
    }
    catch( IOException closeError )
    {
      System.err.printf( "%nError closing %s", ObjInStream );
    }
  }  // end closeObjectInputStream
```

Comment: you're missing a semicolon on `return new ObjectInputStream`

Comment: You could have answered this yourself by simply looking at the highlighting from your IDE.

Comment: And looking at the comment in the code. Voting to close as typo.

Answer (score 1):

The following line is missing a semi-colon (and even then it isn't correct):

```
return new ObjectInputStream  // complete this statement.
```

Without being able to see the rest of your code, perhaps it should be:

```
return inAccount;  // complete this statement.
```